# char changing after returned

Tags: c++, return

This is an attempted solution of a problem on codefights: https://codefights.com/interview-practice/task/FwAR7koSB3uYYsqDp

My BFS function is not returning the correct character despite me printing right before the return and seeing the correct character in the console. It seems the chracter is being mutated for some reason. When I change the function signature to have a std::string return value, the program crashes. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Is it possibly due to lack of freeing pointers or something?

```
typedef struct proTree{
    char value;
    proTree* left;
    proTree* right;
} proTree;

char BFS(std::vector<proTree*> vec, int currLevel, int level, int pos){
    if (currLevel == level){
        if (vec[pos-1]->value == 'E'){
            return 'E';
        } else {
            return 'D';
        }
    }

    std::vector<proTree*> newVec;

    for (int i=0; i<vec.size(); i++){
        newVec.push_back(vec[i]->left);
        newVec.push_back(vec[i]->right);
    }

    BFS(newVec, currLevel+1, level, pos);
}

void createTree(proTree* root, int currLevel, int level){
    if (currLevel == level) return;

    proTree* eTree = new proTree();
    eTree->value = 'E';

    proTree* dTree = new proTree();
    dTree->value = 'D';

    if (root->value=='E'){
        root->left = eTree;
        root->right = dTree;
    } else {
        root->left = dTree;
        root->right = eTree; 
    }

    createTree(eTree, currLevel+1, level);
    createTree(dTree, currLevel+1, level);
}

std::string findProfession(int level, int pos) {
    proTree* eTree = new proTree();
    eTree->value = 'E';
    createTree(eTree, 0, level);
    std::vector<proTree*> vec = {eTree};
    char result = BFS(vec, 0, level, pos);
    if (result == 'E'){
        return "Engineer";
    } else {
        return "Doctor";
    }
}
```

Comment: `typedef struct`is C, you dont use/need it in C++.

Comment: You are leaking memory.

Answer (score 3):

`BFS` does not return anything (actually returned value is undefined) because last function line is missing `return` and the value of recursive function invocation is lost. It should be:

```
return BFS(newVec, currLevel+1, level, pos);
```

You should pay attention to compilation warnings. In this case compiler should've definitely complained about "missing return in function returning non-void" or something similar.

Comment: Most modern compilers are configured to NOT warn about such things by default, but can be configured (e.g. command line options) to do so.

Comment: @Peter most programmers are configured to compile with `-Wall -Wextra` by default and if not they should be configured so.

Comment: @bolov - Such "programmer configuration" is by no means automatic.  Novice questions like this one often arise because someone does NOT know of the value in configuring their compiler, so have not received warnings.   And gcc or clang are not the only compilers - other compilers supply different ways to enable warnings.